# How to prevent user from modifying data in Query datasheet results MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I've got my database on access and when testing it if found that whenever a query is displayed in a datasheet view, the user can actually select any field and modify it and the database saves this modifications !

So is there a way to prevent that from happening either by disable modifying or disabling auto save ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use queries for display to users. Use a form in *DatasheetView*.

Set the form's property *AllowEdits* to *False*. Perhaps also disable insert and delete.

Comment: How to let query result appear in a form ??

Comment: Click to mark the query, go to the ribbon, click _Create_, drop-down _More Forms_, select _Data Sheet_.

Comment: Well it opens in Form view although i set default to Datasheet , however clicking right click results in design view and datasheet view no Form view. How to make it appear in a datasheet right a way

Comment: Don't know what you did. The method described does set DefaultView to DatasheetView. Also, setting this property later does make the form open in DatasheetView.

Comment: Yup found it , When using On_Click() event . The macro used to open form specify the mode view to " Form " , u need to change it to "DataSheet" .